# What is the easiest way to iterate over all the key/value pairs of a java.util.Map in Java 5 and higher?

Tags: java, collections, foreach, java-5

What is the easiest way to iterate over all the key/value pairs of a java.util.Map in Java 5 and higher?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Assuming `K` is your key type and `V` is your value type:

```
for (Map.Entry<K,V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  K key = entry.getKey();
  V value = entry.getValue();
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While [Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/585659/42473) is correct for Java 5, there is a simpler option available starting at Java 10:

```
for (var entry : map.entrySet()) {
    // Do something with entry.getKey() and entry.getValue();
}
```

and Java 8 introduced:

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> {
    // Do something with k, v
});
```

Comment: BTW 1st snippet similar to already suggested one, in accepted answer (from 2009, >24 years ago) but with less details (as posted here, works only with Java 10 or later; question asking for Java 5); (ii) 2nd will not work with Java 5, 6, or 7 :-/

Comment: @user16320675 "in Java 5 and higher".  1st is more readable. 2nd will for newer versions.

Comment: so it will work with Java 5? is my comment wrong? (I think it isn't bad to give some advice to someone reading this answer... even if Java 5 is very old, Java 8 is still being used)

Comment: @user16320675 is right. Your first answer is less detailed, and your second one is **incorrect**! The `.forEach()` method was only made available in Java 8 or newer as part of the [Java 8 Collections Improvements](https://www.javadevjournal.com/java/java-collections/#:~:text=Java%208%20and%20Collections%20Improvements).

Comment: While the question may mention Java 5, it also mentioned _higher_ versions. Since this  was the oldest question with the highest number of votes, it was the first I was offered when doing a search. Although this answer does not provide a Java 5 answer, it does answer the part of the question related to both _easier_ and _higher_, since _higher_ versions of Java *do* provide an _easier_ option than Java 5 does. I can't help but think that the effort which went into criticising this answer, could have, instead, gone into improving it.